# Visual Studio Code change my html code by itself and break all

Tags: ide

Someone know the solution for this:

I have a simple Angular code inside Visual Studio Code and every time i save a file a fragment is changed by itself.

It: `<app-mytag [myVarHere]="myVarHere"></app-mytag>`
becomes it: `<app-mytag></app-mytag>`

by the simple act of save the file.

Im using nano editor outside to solve it.

Its my plugin list:

```
1tontech.angular-material  
4tron.angular-material-snippets  
Angular.ng-template  
AngularDoc.angulardoc-vscode  
EditorConfig.EditorConfig  
GregorBiswanger.json2ts 
HookyQR.beautify  
MarinhoBrandao.Angular2Tests  
NG-42.ng-fortytwo-vscode-extension  
SimonTest.simontest  
UVBrain.Angular2  
abusaidm.html-snippets  
anweber.vscode-tidyhtml  
christian-kohler.npm-intellisense  
christian-kohler.path-intellisense  
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint  
eg2.tslint  
eg2.vscode-npm-script  
esbenp.prettier-vscode  
felixfbecker.php-debug  
felixfbecker.php-intellisense  
felixfbecker.php-pack  
formulahendry.auto-close-tag  
formulahendry.auto-rename-tag  
jasonnutter.search-node-modules  
johnpapa.Angular2  
loiane.angular-extension-pack  
ms-vscode.autorest  
ms-vscode.cpptools  
ms-vscode.typescript-javascript-grammar  
msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome  
pkosta2006.rxjs-snippets  
robertohuertasm.vscode-icons  
steoates.autoimport  
vuhrmeister.vscode-meteor  
waderyan.nodejs-extension-pack  
xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the culprit is [`anweber.vscode-tidyhtml`](https://github.com/AnWeber/vscode-tidyhtml) plugin you are using. The reason why you lose the angular annotations is that, you have enabled  `tidyHtml.formatOnSave` to `true`

You can disable the plugin or try removing `tidyHtml.formatOnSave` from your user settings by going in to:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and type `user settings`

PS - I tried to recreate your problem and here's what happens:

[image: Problem Demo]

Comment: Thanks, it solved, i disabled that and will format by hand. How you did this animation ?